# C# - Invoke Multiple Batch Jobs in Sequential order

Tags: batch-file, c#-4.0

I have three c# console application (Batch Job).

```
   1. Batch A
   2. Batch B
   3. Batch C
```

Batch B should be executed once Batch A is done, and Batch C should be executed once batch B is done.
Right now i have scheduled in Windows scheduler by fixing time. Is there any way to automate this.

Basically I am looking for one Job to be scheduled which will invoke all above three jobs one by one.
Please give me your suggestions.

Comment: Why not use this approach? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419163/from-c-open-an-arbitrary-application

Answer (score 0):

Instead of executing 3 batch files from your C# app consider launching StartBats.bat from C#. Make StartBats.bat launch Batch A, Batch B and Batch C. This will also make it easier for you to add Batch D, etc in the future if need be.

Comment: foreach (file in files.bat) {do stuff} isn't all that much different or more complex and does the same thing while addressing the question directly...