# How to delete a registrykey when selecting on listbox?

Tags: c#, file, listbox, registry

I have added all startup programs to a listbox. How can I delete the selected registry key when I select the item and click on a button?

Listbox code:

```
    private void starting()
    {
        RegistryKey HKCU = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run");
        {
            foreach (string Programs in HKCU.GetValueNames())
            {
                startupinfo.Items.Add(Programs);
            }
            HKCU.Close();
        }
        RegistryKey HKLM = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run");
        {
            foreach (string HKLMPrograms in HKLM.GetValueNames())
            {
                startupinfo.Items.Add(HKLMPrograms);
            }
            HKLM.Close();
        }
```

This the startup folder that I can delete file by file:
(Thanks Rikki-B for helping me)

```
    private void readfiles()
    {
        string startfolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup);

        var files = Directory.GetFiles(startfolder).Where(name => !name.EndsWith(".ini"));

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            startupinfo.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file));
            startupinfoDict.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file), file);
        }
    }
```

this is the button :

```
    private void DisableBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (startupinfo.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        string s = startupinfo.SelectedItem.ToString();

        if (startupinfoDict.ContainsKey(s))
        {
            File.Delete(startupinfoDict[s]);
        }
    }
}
```

How listbox looks like:

[image: 1]

Comment: why lower reputition? I just want to find a way to remove a startup program??

Comment: what is `startupinfoDict` can you show the definition / declaration..

Comment: @DJ KRAZE
Ahh yes this one:
Dictionary<string, string> startupinfoDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

Comment: then you need to remove the `item` based on the `key` so when you debug the code what is the value at this point `startupinfoDict[s]` before you move off of `File.Delete(startupinfoDict[s]);`

Comment: @DJ KRAZE
I'm sorry but I don't understand what to do... can you help me please?

Comment: put a break point on this line `File.Delete(startupinfoDict[s]);` if you are not familiar on how to use the debugger while in the code hit `F9` on that line. debug the code and let me know what the value is

Comment: @DJKRAZE The value will be the path of one the startup *.ini files in the Special folder.

Comment: you say `will be` but have you confirmed that..?

Comment: It looks like this : http://oi47.tinypic.com/ibw4g7.jpg
Thanks for helping by the way!

Comment: what is `startupinfo` if that a List?

Comment: @DJKRAZE Startupinfo is the name of the listbox yes!

Comment: show the definition of startupInfo

Comment: @DJKRAZE
By definition you mean the listbox itself?

<ListBox x:Name="startupinfo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="298" Margin="47,183,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="399" Foreground="#FFBBBBBB" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="#66000000" BorderThickness="5" Cursor="Hand" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectionMode="Multiple" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <ListBox.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect/>
            </ListBox.Effect>
        </ListBox>

Comment: it's a ListBox not a List<T> there is a difference..when you are on that line that I was telling you earlier.. highlight and right click on `startupinfoDict[s]`  and select from the popup menu `QuickWatch` and tell me what the value is

Comment: @DJKRAZE
yes... do you have any solution how to remove the registry keys?
I have showed you all my code about the listbox now :)
I appreciate all your help!

Comment: @DJKRAZE
here is how it looks, Can't find QuickWatch...
http://oi50.tinypic.com/29deez9.jpg

Comment: you have to run the code when it stops on that line in the debugger then you right click and select the `QuickWatch` option

Comment: I just mocked up your code and it appears to be capturing the file Path that you want to delete based on what's selected the only thing that I did that was different than what you are doing is I hard coded the SelectedItemIndex try to wrap the `File.Delete` code around a `try{}catch{}` also make sure you have actual rights / permission to delete from that Directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out.

```
private void DisableBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (startupinfo.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        string s = startupinfo.SelectedItem.ToString();

        if (startupinfoDict.ContainsKey(s))
        {
            try
            {
                File.Delete(startupinfoDict[s]);
            }
            catch
            {
                //errors are here
            }
        }

        string keyName = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run";
        using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(keyName, true))
        {
            if (key != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    key.DeleteValue(startupinfo.SelectedItem.ToString());
                }
                catch
                {
                    //errors are here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked!
I repped you up!

However there is one issue with the code if you don't mind...

This happens when I do the same but deleting a key from HKLM!
Pic: http://oi46.tinypic.com/34sgz0h.jpg

Comment: Just put them in a try/catch block. I edited it for you. You will have to dig a bit deeper to find why they arn't there, but you should have enough to work with.

Comment: Thank you for helping me!
Fixed it for Local Machine too... Thank you again! :)