# How to launch default application for an arbitrary file in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, process, filesystems

How can I start the default program for an arbitrary file from .net?

Eg if I have a `FileInfo` reference to a .mp3 music, I want to launch Windows Media Player (if that's set up as the default handler for the file type)

Consequently if I have .xls, I want to launch Excel with the file pre-opened.

How can I do this from code?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365984/c-sharp-open-file-with-default-application-and-parameters) [seems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162331/finding-the-default-application-for-opening-a-particular-file-type-on-windows/162351#162351) [easily](http://www.csharp-examples.net/open-file-with-default-application/) [googlable](https://www.google.com/search?q=launch+default+application+c%23&oq=launch+default+application+c%23&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l4.5633j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I'll mark this question back up because it's quite possible the google search will lead you to this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use `Process.Start` ([MSDN-article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx))

```
Process.Start(pathToYourFile);
```

Windows will launch the appropriate application. Just watch out: Up until Windows 8, this will throw an exception, if there is no standard application for that file type.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply call `Process.Start(path)` to open any file in the default program.