# How to open a local HTML file in C# on any platform in default browser?

Tags: .net, browser, cross-platform, default

To open a local HTML file in a default browser in .NET I use

```
Process.Start(s);
```

where s is a string like "C:\test.html".

This does not work on Mono in OS X and raises a "DDE Failure" error.

I need to improve the code above so that

1. It opens in MacOS successfully using Mono
2. It actually uses the default browser, not a default handler for HTML files (which could well be Notepad)

I found similar questions on this website but was unable to apply the code therein. I need a piece of code to specifically cover my situation.

EDIT:
This is the exact custom error I am getting: "Error while executing: file://C:\users...\Application Data...\temp\book0.html. Message: DDE failure."

I use the code like this to generate the path:

```
var appDataDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) +          
   Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + appName + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar,
tempDir = appDataDir + "temp" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar,
...
```

But apparently it's not working.

Comment: file path should be like `C:\\test.html` otherwise it will take `\t` as tab.

Comment: thanks, it is like that in my application

Comment: I think it should work `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(s);`

Comment: you can [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365984/c-sharp-open-file-with-default-application-and-parameters) for more detail.