# Open a PDF with Open Parameters Using C# / VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, pdf

The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365984/c-sharp-open-file-with-default-application-and-parameters) regarding how to open a PDF to a specific page using C# is, in summary:

```
Process myProcess = new Process();    
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "acroRd32.exe"; //not the full application path
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/A \"page=2=OpenActions\" C:\\example.pdf";
myProcess.Start();
```

However, this answer appears to be incomplete.  It works great if Adobe Reader (acroRd32.exe) is ***not*** already running, but if Reader ***is*** running, this code won't do anything (at least on my Windows 8.1 PC).  So, how can you open in PDF to a specified page using C# (or VB.NET) *regardless* of whether Adobe Reader is already running?

Comment: What happens if you just pass the process the document name, and don't designate Acrobat as the reader?

Comment: Then you cannot pass the arguments to have the PDF open to a specific page.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the trick is to add the "/n" switch to the arguments string just before the PDF path as follows:

```
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("/A ""zoom={0}&page={1}=OpenActions"" /n ""{2}", strZoom, strPage, strPath)
```

According to the [Acrobat developer FAQ](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/pdf/intro_to_sdk/DeveloperFAQ.pdf), the /n switch "Launches a separate instance of Acrobat or Adobe Reader, even if one is currently open."  I cannot imagine a case where you *wouldn't* want to use this switch (when opening a PDF as described in the OP), so it is surprising that there is little mention of this switch in the dozens of proposed solutions on this topic.