# I want to open a specific video file (mp4) in VLC media player when i press the button in wpf .net core application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, video, vlc

**MAIN WINDOW.xaml:-**

```
<Window x:Class="VIDEO.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VIDEO"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="67" Margin="248,150,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="235" Click="Button_Click"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MAIN WINDOW.xaml.cs:-**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace VIDEO
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Kindly add the code for opening a video file 'sample.mp4' located in :\videos\sample'. I want to open the video file only through VLC media player

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is not a free coding service. Kindly add the code? What did you research?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# open file with default application and parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365984/c-sharp-open-file-with-default-application-and-parameters)