# Visual Studio, Windows Forms C# open a file

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I am creating a Windows Forms notepad. How do I do the button Open to open a file and a specific compatible file? I created the design and know I double-click the event to open the file.

Now I need to code the event to open the file I want. Does anyone know how?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365984/c-sharp-open-file-with-default-application-and-parameters

Comment: @Mehmet_Karadeniz , I don't think that is what he is asking for.

Comment: Look for [OpenFileDialog()](https://www.google.com/search?q=OpenFileDialog+c%23).  Figure it out for yourself using the link provided.  It isn't difficult.

Comment: I did. Thanks you very ...