# C# open file with selected app and specific parameters

Tags: c#

I'm using the answer of this question to solve my problem [c# open file with default application and parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365984/c-sharp-open-file-with-default-application-and-parameters)
But, I need, not only to open the file but inside the default app be able to access the option import... in this moment I can open the file.

Could you indicate me how can I put the specification of import command into the myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments code

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\\Program Files\\Autometrix\\PatternSmith 10.0\\PatternSmith.exe"; 
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\Users\XPLOY-GTS\source\repos\NewRepo\CalculateCoordenates\WpfApp1\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\\Wing0.dxf";
myProcess.Start();
```

[image: Software]

Comment: Does the app support automation?

Comment: I don't know, sorry... The app is not mine. I only need to open files in this app but using the import function

Comment: PatternSmith is a product, you need to find out from the company that makes it what kind support or options they have for automation.