# is there any function in wxwidgets to check pdf software is available or not

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am using wxwidgets 2.8.10 with c++ and I am using both windows xp and windows 7.

Is there any function to see if "pdf" software is available in my computer or not by using wxwidgets?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162331/finding-the-default-application-for-opening-a-particular-file-type-on-windows

Comment: @JohnZwinck: The question is explicitly about the C++ wxWidgets portable API. The linked answer is explicitly about the C# Windows API.

Comment: @DevSolar: you're right.  Hopefully the OP finds it useful!

Comment: Not clear what you are looking for.  How about http://wxcode.sourceforge.net/docs/wxpdfdoc/

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking about. What is *"pdf" software*?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you want to know whether a PDF viewer is available in order to open a PDF document. And if this is the case, you should [just try opening it](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__funcmacro__misc.html#ga04038d4c78e4c111d018b8f82b2d66c3) and then handle the error.