# Why Process.Start method always shows the "Open With" dialog

Tags: c#, wpf, process.start

I'm working on a WPF application that use `Process.Start()` method to open images and PDF files with default viewer app.

What's the problem?

Every time I call `Process.Start()` method the "Open With" dialog shows up even if I check the "Always use this app to open .jpg files"  option.

This is my C# code:

```cs
public void Open(string fileName, bool isPdf)
{
    var sharedFolderPath = AppCore.Settings.SharedFolder.Path;
    string message;

    if (sharedFolderPath is null)
    {
        message = Resources.EmptySharedFolderErrorMessage;
        AppCore.ShowDialog(AppCore.GetMessageDialog(message));
        return;
    }

    var path = Path.Combine(sharedFolderPath, fileName);

    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        try
        {
            if (isPdf || AppCore.Settings.ImageViewerSettings.OpenInWindowsDefaultApp)
            {
                Process.Start(path);
            }
            else
            {
                var imageViewerWindow = new ImageViewerWindow(path);
                imageViewerWindow.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AppCore.Logger.Info("Opening shared file failed.");
            AppCore.Logger.Exception(ex);
        }

        return;
    }

    message = string.Format(Resources.SharedFolderFileNotFoundMessage, fileName);
    AppCore.ShowDialog(AppCore.GetMessageDialog(message));
}
```

My problem with more details:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKWye.jpg

**EDITED**

I created a simple WPF project and tried to open the image with `Process.Start()` method. In the new project the image was opened with the default app without showing "Open With" dialog.

Comment: How about trying to detect what is the current default application to open the file type (https://stackoverflow.com/a/162351/4329813)? Then pass the default application path to Process.FileName

Comment: Looks like there is no default application registered for the filesystem type you are trying to open.

Comment: This is not a problem of the API. This is the default behaviour of Process.Start. Something that the user needs to fix.

Comment: @BionicCode How can I fix this issue?

Comment: In Windows default apps settings Windows 10 Photos app registered for Photo viewer.

Comment: @popsiporkkanaa Nice idea. If I couldn't fix this issue, I'll try that solution.

Comment: Then verify that the path and the extension of the file is correct. Does it work with other files of same type and different type?

Comment: I did before, everything looks ok.

Comment: Hard to believe. This is a simple method that takes a single parameter as input. So it's very likely that the issue is related to this input or the Windows environment. Opening this file using Explorer works? Copying the path and hard code this file opening works? If you just set the default application, tried to reboot the machine? Reboot machine? Clean and rebuild solution. Copy the combined path from your application and paste it into Explorer, does the file open? Can you open the file using ProcessInfo? Then try to specify the target application explicitly, does this work?

Comment: Opening this file using Explorer works? Works everywhere except in my WPF app | If you just set the default application, tried to reboot the machine? Reboot machine? I tried | Copy the combined path from your application and paste it into Explorer, does the file open? Yes, it opens the file

Comment: I'll try in other systems and put the result here.

Comment: Have you tried to execute the application as administrator, does it work? (worth a try)

Comment: I tried now. Same result

Comment: Did you try to set `UseShellExecute` to `true`?

Comment: Also try to execute process.start. from a new blank solution. Just from app.xaml.cs. if this should work you can try to figure out the differences in e.g. Project configuration.

Comment: As I mentioned in the last part of my question. `Process.Start()` Method works fine in other project.

Comment: I got new information about the problem. This issue only occurs for JPG files and only in .net framework (my app framework version 4.7.2). I created a .net core app and everything works like I expected in .net core.

Comment: It's better to use .NET Core instead of .NET Framework for new projects. .NET Framework is discontinued. New features like `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` will be available in .NET Core (or the new consolidated .NET 5.0) only.

Comment: Definitely .net core is better, but in this case some users still using Windows 7 that doesn't support .net core (according to this post: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=netcore31#additional-deps).

Comment: It's supported for Windows 7 SP1 (see [Dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=netcore31#dependencies))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why/how, but my problem solved after uninstalling **TechSmith Snagit** that I installed yesterday.