# Open file:// URI to specific # (hash) ID

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'd like to open a local HTML file navigated to a specific headline with an ID.
`string url = "file:///C:/myFile.html#myHeading"`
If I paste the URL in the browser directly, it correctly navigates to the desired heading.
But when I try to have the system handle the URL, it omits the hash entirely.

```
ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo(url);
si.UseShellExecute = true;
Process.Start(si);
```

will simply open `file:///C:/myFile.html`.

Is there a way I can make this work?
Sadly, I don't know where this stripping happens, so my research so far turned up empty.
I tried replacing the hash symbol with its escaped form `%23`, which of course didn't work (could not find the file specified).

### A work-around I'm using in the meantime:

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162331/finding-the-default-application-for-opening-a-particular-file-type-on-windows), I wrote an extension which tells me the path to the executable set as the default app for opening files with a given extension.

```
public static string getDefaultAssociation(string extension)
{
    if (extension.Substring(0, 1) != ".")
    {
        int os = extension.IndexOf('.');
        if (os > 0)
        {
            extension = extension.Substring(os);
        }
        else
        {
            extension = "." + extension;
        }
    }
    const int S_OK = 0;
    const int S_FALSE = 1;

    uint length = 0;
    uint ret = AssocQueryString(AssocF.None, AssocStr.Executable, extension, null, null, ref length);
    if (ret != S_FALSE)
    {
        //throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not determine associated string");
        WriteLog("Could not determine associated string");
        return "";
    }

    var sb = new StringBuilder((int)length); // (length-1) will probably work too as the marshaller adds null termination
    ret = AssocQueryString(AssocF.None, AssocStr.Executable, extension, null, sb, ref length);
    if (ret != S_OK)
    {
        //throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not determine associated string");
        WriteLog("Could not determine associated string");
        return "";
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}

[DllImport("Shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern uint AssocQueryString(
    AssocF flags,
    AssocStr str,
    string pszAssoc,
    string pszExtra,
    [Out] StringBuilder pszOut,
    ref uint pcchOut
);

[Flags]
public enum AssocF
{
    None = 0,
    Init_NoRemapCLSID = 0x1,
    Init_ByExeName = 0x2,
    Open_ByExeName = 0x2,
    Init_DefaultToStar = 0x4,
    Init_DefaultToFolder = 0x8,
    NoUserSettings = 0x10,
    NoTruncate = 0x20,
    Verify = 0x40,
    RemapRunDll = 0x80,
    NoFixUps = 0x100,
    IgnoreBaseClass = 0x200,
    Init_IgnoreUnknown = 0x400,
    Init_Fixed_ProgId = 0x800,
    Is_Protocol = 0x1000,
    Init_For_File = 0x2000
}

public enum AssocStr
{
    Command = 1,
    Executable,
    FriendlyDocName,
    FriendlyAppName,
    NoOpen,
    ShellNewValue,
    DDECommand,
    DDEIfExec,
    DDEApplication,
    DDETopic,
    InfoTip,
    QuickTip,
    TileInfo,
    ContentType,
    DefaultIcon,
    ShellExtension,
    DropTarget,
    DelegateExecute,
    Supported_Uri_Protocols,
    ProgID,
    AppID,
    AppPublisher,
    AppIconReference,
    Max
}
```

So I can use

```
string def = getDefaultAssociation("html");
ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo(def);
si.Arguments = url;
si.UseShellExecute = true;
Process.Start(si);
```

to directly tell my default browser to go to the file URL, INCLUDING the ID hash.

Comment: Also, a more elegant way might be to use a `WebBrowser` Control in-app to display the file and navigate to the desired ID, if that's feasible for your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File scheme (`file://`) just doesn't support anchors or actually any parameters, according to [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8089). So query string, anchors or anything else besides path to file can be ignored by whatever processes url with this scheme, which is what happens here. If you try `file:///C:/myFile.html?x=1` - query string will also be stripped. If on the other hand you'll try `http://google.com?x=1#test` then it will open exactly this url in browser, because other scheme.

So I'd say it works as expected and your workaround is fine.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! It's a bit disappointing that the scheme is so much less than it could be, but understandable.